# Tomcat 6.0 Deployment Error

Tags: web-services, apache, jakarta-ee, tomcat, jax-ws

I am having problems deploying my web application, and it has been puzzling me for 3 weeks after continually blaming our hosting company and their server.

First of all, the web application was deploying fine using manager on tomcat 5.

Then I asked to change to tomcat 6, which they did, and now the application does not deploy and gives the now all so familiar SEVERE: Error deploying configuration descriptor XXXX.xml.

BUT in Eclipse I build and run my application on Tomcat 6 which works fine!, but when again when I try and deploy the packaged war on my local server via manager, I get the SEVERE error.

There is something wrong with my deployment descriptor which is sensitive to tomcat but not in eclipse. I read somewhere about case sensitive and I have double checked this.

I have then tried and commented out the context - still does not work, and everything in web.xml apart from the welcome-file-list. Still I get the same error.

I am out of ideas and very confused.

Below I have posted web.xml and context.xml (for confidentiality reasons I have to XXXX out the names).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>XXXX</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>restSdkService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
      <param-value>com.XXXX.core.TestWebApp</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>restSdkService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <resource-ref>
    <description>MySQL Datasource example</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/XXXX</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>

</web-app>
```

context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
<Resource name="jdbc/emotifi" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
               username="XXXX" password="XXXX" 
               driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
               url="XXXX"/>

<Resource name="jdbc/emotifi_web" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
               username="XXXX" password="XXXX" 
               driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
               url="XXXX"/>

 </Context>
```

Comment: The same problem was experienced here https://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/170469, but there is no real solution or explanation

Comment: And the full stack trace from the logs is ... ?

Comment: Non of the logs report more than the given error, which is the frustrating part. Is there a way to configure tomcat to dump the stack trace?

Comment: Just found (and fixed for 7.0.x) the place where that error is logged without the exception. It is the parsing of the context.xml that is failing. I don't see anything obviously wrong. Try removing the Resource elements and then adding them back one bit at a time until you find what is triggering the problem.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks, I tried everything but nothing worked. I ended up creating a new project and just copying all my code over, and it worked! This is obviously a weird bug somewhere, or the project may have got corrupted somewhere under version control? Either way it remains a mystery as there is nothing wrong with any of the code!